# “Fully-wrapped” only-child selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to select the `<em>` element in the first table only, not the second. Is there any CSS selector to do so?

TO CLARIFY: I only want to select `<em>` inside `<p>` following a table, only if em is fully wrapped into p. i.e.: if `<p>` contains nothing but `<em>`.

In passing, I'm not sure what to call sections `What do you think about` and `thing?` inside of the last `<p>` element. Technically, they're not siblings elements since they're not elements.

I want to do so in CSS alone.

```
<table>
<td>blah</td>
</table>
<p><em>My name is legend</em></p>


<table>
<td>blah</td>
</table>
<p>What do you think about <em>this</em> thing?</p>
```

This is what I've got so far, but this is too broad and selects both:

```
table + p > em:only-child {
    color: red;
}
```

[Demo here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jypkqhsc/1/)

Comment: I think this not looks possible in pure css. However If you wrap text before and after `em` in some inline element like `span` then your selector will work fine.

Comment: No...this is not possible without an HTML markup change. Text nodes are not "detectable" by CSS. JS would be required.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
table:first-of-type + p > em:only-child {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I don't care so much about the table order as I do about the structure. i.e.: I only want to select em if it's the only element wrapped into p. Updated the question with a link to a jsfiddle.